# Remote API is extremely slow

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use the remote API for some utility tasks, and I've noticed that it is orders of magnitude slower than code running on Appengine. A simple get_by_id(list) took a couple of minutes using the remote API, and a couple of seconds running on Appengine.

The logs show that the remote API fetched separately taking a couple of seconds each; whereas on Appengine the whole list of objects is retrieved in about the same time.

Is there any way to improve this situation?

Comment: How big is the list? Do you have any active instance running on the cloud when you tested that? How long does it usually take to startup your instance? Which runtime are you using?

Comment: Updated my answer with a real workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tested it myself and found that fetching 1000 entities takes really long time. I feel like the remote_api client makes one request for each entity in this case. This is because the default option for our datastore API call was changed. You can fasten the call by setting max_entity_groups_per_rpc config option on the call. Here is an example:

```
config = db.create_config(max_entity_groups_per_rpc=50)
entities = MyModel.get_by_id(l, config=config)
# or
entities = db.get(key_list, config=config)
```

Or, querying with keys was much faster, so if your key list is sequential, and you can build a query with key range like:

```
MyModel.all().filter('__key__ >=', db.Key.from_path('MyModel', 1)).\
  filter('__key__ <', db.Key.from_path('MyModel', 1001))
```

you can workaround this.

Comment: In my testing, the remote API still did one request per entity, despite adding the config parameter. And I believe that get_by_id() was essentially a key query - the id is translated to a key before the API call.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that the remoteapi executes your code locally and only calls appengine servers for datastore/blobstore/etc. operations. So in essence, you're running code that's hitting a database living over the network. It's definitely slower.